# Can we append URL parameters to an endpoint based on values in a test case?

Tags: testing, chatbot

Is it possible to send input parameters to the chatbot from test cases, both with and without user input? What I have in mind is that I should be able to do this in the test cases:

```
Test case 1 

#me
Hello
INPUT_PARAMETER sttConfidence : 0.58
INPUT_PARAMETER callerCountry : GB

#bot
Hi human! I see that you sent some input parameters. Thank you!
...
...
```

The input parameters need to be appended to the endpoint, so the URL would look like this:

https://MyChatBotsEndpoint.com/?userinput={{msg.messageText}}&sttConfidence=0.58& callerCountry=GB

The values that we send need to be of type string.

Is this possible to achieve in Botium? And if yes, are there any native tools in Botium that can achieve this, or do we need to develop our own function?

Edit: 
This is what happens when I added the piece of code:
[Example of how input parameter merges with input message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGNT6.png)

Ideally I would like it to look like this:

[This is what it looks like if I manually send &countryCaller=GB to our endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsbTB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like that included, but with the right combination of a logic hook and the HTTP/JSON request hook it is possible.

The [UPDATE_CUSTOM](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/48660497/Integrated+Logic+Hooks) logic hook will copy the parameters from the convo file to the internal Botium message object:

```
Test case 1 

#me
Hello
UPDATE_CUSTOM QUERY_PARAM|sttConfidence|0.58
UPDATE_CUSTOM QUERY_PARAM|callerCountry|GB

#bot
Hi human! I see that you sent some input parameters. Thank you!
...
```

The [SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24510469/Generic+HTTP+S+JSON+Connector#SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK) capability will then use the parameters to adapt the request url accordingly with a little Javascript code:

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK": "if (msg.QUERY_PARAM) requestOptions.uri = requestOptions.uri + '&' + Object.keys(msg.QUERY_PARAM).map(key => key + '=' + msg.QUERY_PARAM[key]).join('&')",
...
```

**Alternative Approach**

If you don't like the SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK Javascript code, you could also use Mustache templates to add the query parameters to the URL:

```
...
"SIMPLEREST_URL": "https://MyChatBotsEndpoint.com/?userinput={{msg.messageText}}&sttConfidence={{msg.QUERY_PARAM.sttConfidence}}&callerCountry={{msg.QUERY_PARAM.callerCountry}}"
...
```

(you will have empty parameters, but you can tune this mustache template as you want to exclude empty parameters).

Comment: I tried the first approach as it allows for a more dynamic use.
 
The code almost gets it right, 
UPDATE_CUSTOM QUERY_PARAM|callerCountry|GB 

For example,

#me
Hello
UPDATE_CUSTOM QUERY_PARAM|callerCountry|GB

Creates the userinput:
HellocallerCountry=GB

It looks like the input parameters gets added to the msg.messageText instead of {{msg.messageText}}&callerCountry=GB

Got any ideas how I could solve this? I’ve updated my original post with some images to illustrate what it looks like and what I want it to look like.

Comment: As you already have query params attached to your request URI, you additionally have to add the "&" separator in the SIMPLEREST_REQUEST_HOOK - updated OP.